# Explicit example of an algebraically closed field of cardinality greater than continuum.

Tags: field-theory, set-theory

Is there an explicit example, in ZFC, of an algebraically closed field whose cardinality is greater than the cardinality of the set of real numbers? I would be very interested in such an example.

Comment: See [this MO post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/296070/algebraically-closed-field-of-cardinality-greater-than-mathfrak-c).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a construction: For any set $X$, consider the ring $\mathbb{Z}[X] = \mathbb{Z}[(x)_{x\in X}]$, the ring of polynomials with integer coefficients and variables from $X$. Alternatively, this is the free ring generated by $X$. It is a domain, and its fraction field is $\mathbb{Q}(X) = \mathrm{Frac}(\mathbb{Z}[X])$, the field of rational functions with variables from $X$. Let $\overline{\mathbb{Q}(X)}$ be the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{Q}(X)$.

Then $\overline{\mathbb{Q}(X)}$ is an algebraically closed field of characteristic $0$ and cardinality $\max(|X|,\aleph_0)$. In particular, if $|X|>2^{\aleph_0}$, then $|\overline{\mathbb{Q}(X)}| = |X|>2^{\aleph_0}$.

In fact, *every* algebraically closed field $K$ of characteristic $0$ is isomorphic to one of the form $\overline{\mathbb{Q}(X)}$, where $X$ is a transcendence basis of $K$ over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Similarly, every algebraically closed field $K$ of characteristic $p$ is isomorphic to one of the form $\overline{\mathbb{F}_p(X)}$, where $X$ is a transcendence basis of $K$ over $\mathbb{F}_p$.